# How to pass class object to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `BarcodeReaderActivity` which I'll start in a couple of activities and before I start this `Activity`, I want to pass a destination`Activity` class for this `BarcodeReaderActivity` so after reading QR code, I want it to open destination `Activity` with `Intent`.

My first solution is to pass destination class name as string and use switch case in `BarcodeReaderActivity` and write specific `Intent` for that class.

I also tried to create `BarcodeReader`as `Fragment` first but then when I start the destination `Activity` and then remove the `Fragment` it shows the previous `Activity` for a short amount of time but I don't want that to happen.

I would like to get some advice from you, if you know a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build required `Intent` outside `BarcodeReaderActivity` and pass it as extra. If needed you can change this intent later in `BarcodeReaderActivity`.
Something like this:

```
Intent finalIntent = new Intent( context, FinalActivity.class );
Intent barcodeIntent = new Intent( context, BarcodeReaderActivity.class );
barcodeIntent.putExtra( "finalintentkey", finalIntent);
context.startActivity(barcodeIntent);
```

then in your `BarcodeReaderActivity` retrieve intent (and modify it as needed):

```
Intent finalIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra( "finalintentkey" );
// if needed modify intent here
finalIntent.addExtra( "somekey", someneededvalue );
startActivity( finalIntent );

// BarcodeReaderActivity can be finished now
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects between Android Activities. The best way to do it is to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface from Android SDK. After that, you can add your object to the Intent responsible for starting new Activity with `putExtra("parcelName", object)` method.To read Parcelable object in antoher activity you can use such code snippet:

`getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("parcelName")`

I've found nice example presenting this idea here: http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Moreover, if you want to avoid tons of boilerplate code, you can use [auto-parcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) library, which can generate some repeatable stuff for you.